# Why do insert privledges not show on session_privs?

Tags: oracle, privileges

I did a `select * from session_privs` to find out what privledges my current user had, and it gave me a list of create privledges, including create table.

However, I'm able to insert rows into the table. Why is insert not listed in session_privs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between privileges (CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE ANY SEQUENCE, etc) and grants (grant select,insert,update on tab_a to user_b, etc).

SESSION_PRIVS will display the privileges that the current session has.

DBA_TAB_PRIVS will show you what grants a user has to what tables.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Obligatory disclaimer: Neither includes permissions granted through roles. Finding all your permissions for real is a pain in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Check view `USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD` or `USER_TAB_PRIVS`, there you see all privileges on tables, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS_RECD WHERE PRIVILEGE = 'INSERT';
```

The name is a bit misleading, because it also shows grants on other objects, e.g. `GRANT EXECUTE ON <procedure_name>`